# Element class names with different values in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I'm trying to update multiple circle bars on a array of data coming from the database.
Here is my html:

```html
<div class="row pie-charts">    
  <ba-card *ngFor="let goal of pGoal; let i = index"  class = "pie-chart-item-container col-xlg-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="pie-chart-item">
      <div class = "pie-chart-item">
        <div class="circle-{{i}}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="description">
        <div>{{ goal.Name }}</div>
        <div class="description-stats">{{ goal.GoalDescription }}</div>
      </div>
      <i class="chart-icon i-person"></i>
  </ba-card>
</div>
```

Here is my angular code:

```html
ngOnInit() {
      this._personalgoalsService.getGoalSummary()
        .subscribe( result => {
          this.pGoal = result;
         jQuery('.circle-0').circliful({
         percent: 33
       });
      jQuery('.circle-1').circliful({
         percent: 88
        });
      })
  }
```

If I hard code the class name when I run circliful (or any other js chart) they all get updated with the same values.  There must be easy way to create multiple objects of the same class names with different values.  So I tried to use the ngFor and add the - index number.  It seems when I create a class or id dynamically in html it doesn't get created correctly in the dom and then I can't find it in the js.

Thanks,

Edit:
Basically I was trying to update the same "element" with different values.  I wasn't sure how to create multiple circle graphs of the same type with different values.

```html
<div class="row pie-charts">  
  <circle *ngFor="let goal of goals | async" [goal]="goal"></circle> 
</div>
```

So I created a component and passed in my goal object.  But I still wasn't getting a unique element to create the circle.  Actually my array of goals was 2, but I was getting 4 graphs drawn with the same default value.

Then I created a CircleDirective :

```html
@Directive(
  {
    selector: '[myCircle]'
  }
)

export class CircleDirective implements OnInit{
  @Input() goal : iPersonalGoalModel;
  private el: HTMLElement;
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    jQuery(this.el).circliful({
      percent : this.goal.GoalCompletionPercentage
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  directives: [CircleDirective],
  providers: [],
  styles: [require('./circle.css')],
  template: require('./circle.html')
})

export class CircleComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() goal : iPersonalGoalModel;

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.goal.GoalCompletionPercentage);
    }
}
```

So now my component is using the circle directive.  This directive is called in the circle.html.

```html
<div myCircle
    class="circle" 
    [goal]="goal"
    data-dimension="250" 
    data-info="Sweet" 
    data-width="30" 
    data-fontsize="38" 
    data-fgcolor="#61a9dc" 
    data-bgcolor="#eee" 
    data-fill="#ddd" 
    data-total="100" 
>
</div
```

Notice two things here.  I'm using the attribute myCircle and I'm passing the goal through to the circle directive.  I know there are some ways to clean this up, but this works.  It only displays two circle graphs and with the two correct values.

The frustration was I knew what the problem was, but I ran around the solution.  The problem right now there is multiple solutions for the same problem that are simplistic in nature.  I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? do you want to use arbitrary class name on certain object or construct class names and get jQuery object with corresponding class names?

Comment: Consider separating the process of getting data from the process of displaying circles. Instead, get the data into an array of objects with the circle data. Separately use the ngFor to loop through that retrieved data and set the appropriate attributes with the data values.

Comment: <div class="circle"></div> works just fine. If I add more than one circle class and update the percentage, jQuery('.circle') will update all circles in the DOM with the same percentage.  I wanted to dynamically create class names in the html that I could then reference in jQuery to set each individual circle's percentage.  When I use the above code to dynamically set it, it creates the class name, but the element created isn't the same.  the jQuery command to find it, doesn't.  How do I dynamically create a class name so I can run the circliful function on that dynamically created class?